# The method setLocalDispatchPeriod(int) from the type GAServiceManager is deprecated

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have latest Google analytics SDK for android and seems like `setLocalDispatchPeriod(int)` has been deprecated. What is the fix for this ?

There is no where in the internet I could find alternate method for this. And most funniest thing is, google has used this method in their own tutorial of [how to get started.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced#example)

Now does does anybody knows any alternate method ?

Comment: it says "By default, data is dispatched from the Google Analytics SDK for Android every 30 minutes. " so just delete the method, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the deprecation is outlined in the `ServiceManager` JavaDoc:

> This only works if local dispatching is in use. Local dispatching is
>   only used in the absence of Google Play Services on the device or if
>   manually forced (see setForceLocalDispatch()). In general,
>   applications can not rely on the ability to set the dispatch period.
>   This method should therefore be used with some discretion.

If you are using `EasyTracker`, you can also specify `ga_dispatchPeriod` in your analytics.xml file, which should not throw a lint warning about deprecation.

```
<resources>
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

  <!-- [...] -->
</resources>
```

See the [Dispatching page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/dispatch) of the docs.