# Google Analytics Dispatch period with Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using the latest version of Google Play Services in order to use Google Analytics with my Android app. I'm trying to set the dispatch interval to only 1 second so I can see it in the real-time analytics dashboard. However, it's taking at least 3 minutes before it shows up in real-time. How can I get it to show up right away or within a minute?

Here's my code:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
final Tracker t = analytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXX-X");
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1);
```

I need to do it programmatically and not in an XML file.
I should also mention that I'm tracking an event. It seems to be consistently showing up in real-time analytics 3 minutes later.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use real time api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

Answer (score 2):

`setLocalDispatchPeriod()` is deprecated for quite some time now.

> The reason for the deprecation is outlined in the ServiceManager
>   JavaDoc:
>
> This only works if local dispatching is in use. Local dispatching is
>   only used in the absence of Google Play Services on the device or if
>   manually forced (see setForceLocalDispatch()). In general,
>   applications can not rely on the ability to set the dispatch period.
>   This method should therefore be used with some discretion.
>
> If you are using EasyTracker, you can also specify ga_dispatchPeriod
>   in your analytics.xml file, which should not throw a lint warning
>   about deprecation.

```
<resources>
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1</integer>

  <!-- [...] -->
</resources>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618219/3848666 by [Tanis.7x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253844/tanis-7x)